# R presentations reveal js - how to add section title or name for table of contents

Tags: r, reveal.js

Reveal js in R is super cool, however, I struggle with the table of contents. I know I can use  `# title` if I only use the markdown, however, I am using `<section><\section>` for additional functionality. So my slides look something like this

```
<section background-transition: slide data-background="images/clouds3.png" height=30%>
<img src="./images/blue.png"  style="float: center;" class="plain">    <br>  
<br> 
<p align='left'>
<br>
Data science, ML, AI,..</p>

::: incremental
-  What is it?  
- What skills are involved?  
- What are some tools?  
- <p style="font-size:40px"> Why do we need it?   </p>
<p style="font-size:30px">
- What do we do at WD?  </p>
::: 

<img src="./images/lifterguy.png" style="float: right;" class="plain" width=30%> 
 
</section>
```

My toc looks like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8unVG.png)

How can I add titles in toc using `<section>`?